# How to send a Python Variable to shell commands?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am trying to send a variable from my code in Python to a shell command in Ubuntu. Can anyone help me with how to do that? Currently, I have

```
import os
s=5
command = os.popen('stress -c 5 -i 1 -m 1 --vm-bytes 128M -t s')
```

I want to send the `s` variable to this command instead of directly say the time of time-out.

Answer (score 4):

Use the standard subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
s = 5
cmd = ['stress', '-c', '5', '-i', '1', '-m', '1',
      '--vm-bytes', '128M', '-t', str(s)]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Using the subprocess module, allows each argument to be passed separately and distinctly.  You only have to convert them to strings.

Comment: The first method won't work if the value of `s` itself contains double quotes. The second method is really the only reliable method.

Comment: Sure, and I also agree the second method is more reliable. However, in my case the first method works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the 's' in your command string is what you want to assume the value of your variable 's'?  All you need to do is this:

```
command = os.popen('stress -c 5 -i 1 -m 1 --vm-bytes 128M -t ' + str(s))
```

If I misread it and you are trying to replace the 5, it is basically the same

```
command = os.popen('stress -c ' + str(s) + ' -i 1 -m 1 --vm-bytes 128M -t s')
```

Comment: While it will work, it's a bad habit. Either the values included in a command line should be properly escaped, or the command should be split into tokens on Python's side. If `s` comes from an untrusted source, it could be `; rm -rf / ;`

Comment: @viraptor I agree about the escaping, but it looked like the variable was a constant in the OP's script so it was safe to do the quick version.  As a technicality, `rm -rf /` doesn't work (I've tested it), you need `rm -rf /*` since rm won't let you delete root.  Even then there are a handful of files it won't let you delete, but that will make the os nearly unusable.

Comment: I know it doesn't work - that's why I'm always using the broken version in examples :)

Comment: @viraptor Maybe I shouldn't have had all those drinks and played command line russian roulette that one night...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using for example Google Colab and you are running the code with "!" in a line, you can put "$" behind the variable.
for example:

```
folderName = "somedir"
!mkdir $folderName
```

or

```
!mkdir {folderName}
```

All according to [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851718/how-to-use-python-variables-in-google-colab-terminal-command)

Answer (score -2):

This is a string replacement operation which you can get all the info [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Or you can just concatenate the strings together. ([good tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python))

Comment: Use external links to support your answer, not as the entire answer itself.

Comment: I believe that the answer is string replacement and the links are supporting the answer by giving details how to do that....

Comment: There is no way to *use* this answer without consulting the external resource if you don't already know what the string replacment operation is. It's also not a good answer in the presence of quoting issues.

Comment: So what you are saying as long as I don't do the whole work and give exactly what is needed it is not an answer that is supposed to be accepted at all?

Comment: I see what you mean I didn't give enough context for the link, will do next time :).