# How to use Python variables in Google Colab terminal command?

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-colaboratory

I have a cell with this content:

```
import os
os.mkdir('123')
name = '123'
!rm -r name
```

I want to pass the value of the variable *name* to the last line.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Try `$`. It will substitute the python variable.

```
!rm -r $name
```

You may need to use `$name\.txt` or `{name}.txt` in some cases.

Comment: This does not work with the following command `!git clone https://$GITHUB_AUTH@github.com/$user/my-repo.git`, where `user` is a Python variable and `$GITHUB_AUTH` corresponds to `os.environ['GITHUB_AUTH']`, which is correctly replaced with the corresponding value in the command above, as opposed to the variable `user`, which is replaced with an empty string.

Comment: @nbro I would recommend using quotes in your shell command:
`!git clone "https://"$GITHUB_AUTH"@github.com/"$user"/my-repo.git"`.
I use similar command for managing git and files from buckets and it works perfectly for me :)

Comment: and you may also consider adding quotes around your $variableName in case it has spaces or other chars which will break the command. e.g. `!rm -r "$name"`

Answer (score 12):

Use `{}`.

```
myvar = "/test"
!cd {myvar}
```

According to
https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/01.05-IPython-And-Shell-Commands.ipynb#scrollTo=q-zpo3vGM5Jv

Comment: Thanks for edit, now it looks even nicer.
Btw. the #scrollTo is broken. You have to scroll yourself to find the source.