# How can I accept an input in google colab then use that input throughout the code (specifically in shell commands)?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I understand there are [forms](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/forms.ipynb), but not how to take a form input from one cell and use the input in other multiple cells.

Thank you!

I've looked into forms, but they only work for very basic code. I am trying to run a python program which means I have the cell code as

```
!python3 <nameofprogram>.py -flags arguments
```

The arguments are what I'd like to change, however even with a dropdown form selection, I can't get the code to understand that the argument is from a form, instead of taking the literal text which doesn't when I change the dropdown.

Here's the cell's code:

```
Section = "tracks" #@param ["tracks", "newalbums", "justreleased", "pop", "rock", "electronic", "country", "hiphop", "rnb", "kpop", "classical", "jazz", "latin", "holiday"]
!python3 redsea.py -a TV explore atmos Section
```

I see no answers that help me.

The final answer I found was to use $ before the piece in the code.

```
!python3 redsea.py -a TV explore atmos $Section
```

After asking for the input.

Comment: It is not clear why you are asking multiple times for the same information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can prompt the user for input using the `input` function like so:

```
file_name = input('Enter the file name: ')
print(f'You entered {file_name}')
```

Here's a full example:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OXsj6GqG76AK7DE-DUPo0zGOiiZjYwX0?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `input()`.

```
name = input("Your name: ")
```

Then in another cell, you can use the `name` variable.

Here's a [notebook](https://colab.to/1Ze7nMeEPJBHgYOUUjIxy6YOdogjMG0LS) to test.

Answer (score 0):

The OP was asking how to use the Python input in shell commands (running with the `!...`).

The existing answers **don't answer that question**; the OP answered their own question; **they use `$python_var` before the Python variable `python_var`**  (known as "variable expansion")

The existing answers suggest using `input(...)`, which **still requires using the `$python_var`** if passing the Python variable into a shell (so you don't **need** to use `input(...)`, you can use [forms](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/forms.ipynb) / `Insert > Add a form field`) to get the input in the first place (which is nice; forms have dropdowns and checkboxes and forms can "react" to your choice)...

Another option **is to use `{python_var}` around the Python variable** as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68498737/1175496) and [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/01.05-IPython-And-Shell-Commands.ipynb#scrollTo=SkR123CfCGKY) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35497161/1175496) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606054/passing-ipython-variables-as-string-arguments-to-shell-command))

Example:

```
say = 'hi'
!echo {say}
```

Outputs:

```
hi
```

Another example that uses #forms (as the OP asked...)

```
#@title Choose a genre (auto-run) { run: "auto" }
genre = "newalbums" #@param ["tracks", "newalbums", "jazz", "latin", "holiday"]
!echo You picked genre: {genre}
```

Output (will re-run automatically as the user makes a different choice; see `{ run: "auto" }` in the above)

```
You picked genre: newalbums
```

I think this syntax (for `!` bang aka shell escaping, and the variable expansion aka interpolation) comes from [IPython/Jupyter](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#shell-assignment), which says:

> The line after the bang can call any program installed in the
> underlying shell, and support variable expansion in the form of
> `$variable` or `{variable}`. The later form of expansion supports
> arbitrary python expressions: